# Theming views data export XLS button

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that I have attached a data export view to. I want to change the default orange icon that shows XLS at the bottom of the view, to another button with text "Download View". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This image is set in function views_data_export_views_plugins(), in views_data_export.views

Implement your own [hook_views_plugins()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_plugins/7) and override `['style']['views_data_export_xls']['export feed icon']` with your own value. Just make sure your module [fires after](http://drupal.org/node/110238) Views Data Export.

Comment: How will I ensure that my module fires after Views Data Export

Comment: Click a link I put there?

Answer (score 1):

**Revised Answer:**
Seems dreadfully hacky, but it is a fix in one place where my earlier answer was CSS and preprocess. I found that as soon as the CSV link had filter arguments appended then the CSS `a[href$='.csv']` targeting broke.

```
THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view($vars){

    if(!empty($vars['feed_icon'])){

    $vars['feed_icon'] = str_replace('sites/all/modules/views_data_export/images/csv.png', drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEMENAME').'/images/feed-icon-csv.png', $vars['feed_icon']);
    $vars['feed_icon'] = str_replace('sites/all/modules/kml/images/kml.png', drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEMENAME').'/images/feed-icon-kml.png', $vars['feed_icon']);

    }
}
```

---

**Old answer** that does not work if the view has query parameters:

I did the following to strip out those images but leave the links:

```
THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view($vars){
    if($vars['view']->name == 'view_name'){

        $vars['feed_icon'] = strip_tags($vars['feed_icon'], '<a>');

    }
}
```

Then in my CSS I could easily add:

```
.feed-icon a[href$='.csv'] {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('images/feed-icon-csv.png');
    width: 94px;
    height: 27px;
}
```

Yes I know it is not great for accessibility but hooks were really not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple hook into the _views_data_export_feed_icon Function (like above).
The Function above doesn't work for me.

So here is mine:

```
function YOURMODULEORTHEME_views_data_export_feed_icon($variables) 
{
    extract($variables, EXTR_SKIP);
    $url_options = array('html' => TRUE, 'attributes' => array('class' => 'YOURCLASS-button'));
    if($query) {
        $url_options['query'] = $query;
    }
    return l($text, $url, $url_options);
}
```

You could specify your own class to style the Button.

The "alt" Text (defined in the View) is now your Link.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what was posted above, however, you need to do it in [hook_views_plugins_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_plugins_alter/7) rather than defining your own plugin in hook_views_plugins().

Set the export feed icon to your updated icon:

```
function MYMODULE_views_plugins_alter(&$plugins) {
  $plugins['style']['views_data_export_xls']['export feed icon'] = [PATH_TO_MY_ICON];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

override theme_views_data_export_feed_icon function in your theme template.php

Example :

```
function themename_views_data_export_feed_icon($image_path, $url, $query = '', $text = '') {

    $url_options = array('html' => true, 'attributes' => array('class' => 'csv-export'));
    if ($query) {
       $url_options['query'] = $query;
    }
    return l(t('Download View'), $url, $url_options);
}
```

Comment: And by the way, it does not answer the question - default RSS feed icon has nothing to do with views data export XLS button.

Comment: How the export button will come at top of my view? I need to change any configuration or will it come automatically? For my views it is not showing.